# Find/Count documents by partial _id value in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to find documents in my collections via partial _id values that I enter in a GUI application.
After some searching I found out that I could at least find documents by it's partial id using the following filter:

```
{ $where: "this._id.str.match(/5a.*/)" }
```

(where `5a` is the partial id value the user entered)

My server application that handles these searches also supports pagination so I always query the database to count/estimate the number of matching documents.
If I however put this `$where` expression into my `FilterDefinition` that I pass to `CountDocumentsAsync()` of my collection, I just get an exception:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: $where is not allowed in this context
```

I then looked up the `countDocuments` method of MongoDB and found out that the `$where` operator is not allowed in `countDocuments()` and one should use `$expr` instead.

Unfortunately I couldn't get anything working with `$expr` as I couldn't find any useful examples that would help me with my specific requirements.
I just tried to wrap the `$where` expression in an `$expr` expression but that doesn't seem to work (`Command aggregate failed: Unrecognized expression '$where'`)

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your _id is of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) type, you can [convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) it to string (available from [v4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#new-type-conversion-operators)) then regex it without using expensive javascript evaluation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { 
        _idString: { $toString: "$_id" } 
    } },
    { $match: { _idString: /5a.*/ } }
] )
```

As a side note, the regexp `/5a.*/` matches exactly same strings as `/5a/` does.